# Create new array of objects that have a specific property/attribute in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I have an array of objects with a boolean attribute:

```
[#<Animal id: 1, type: "narwhal", magical: false>, #<Animal id: 2, type: "unicorn", magical: true>]
```

How do I create a new array with only the objects where the boolean `:magical?` is true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for [Enumerable#select](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Enumerable.html%23method-i-select)?

```
a = [#<Animal id: 1, type: "narwhal", magical: false>, #<Animal id: 2, type: "unicorn", magical: true>]
b = a.select(&:magical?)
b
=> [#<Animal id: 2, type: "unicorn", magical: true>]
```

Comment: @CarySwoveland: I like it improves readability and makes it really obvious that it returns `true`/`false` not just a trueish or falseish value.

Comment: @spickerman, that converts the method `magical?` to a proc, but we haven't been told about a method by that name. Am I missing something? I'll check back in the morning.